# Merge two tables together using insert statement to match exact values into table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables and I am trying to see how best to merge them into the first table using insert.

Table 1 Fields:

| date | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | 0 | 3 |

Table 2 fields:

| date | cat_type | cat_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-04 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-04 | 3 | 2 |

I want to get the table 2 fields into table 1. How can I best do this? I am trying the following

```
INSERT INTO table 1 (FILE_DATE, cat_1, cat_2,cat_3) 
                FROM
                (SELECT DATE,
                    CASE WHEN cat_type = 2 THEN 'INSERT CAT_COUNT INTO CAT_2)
                    END
                FROM TABLE_2)
```

Comment: what do you want the table to look like after you merged them?

Comment: Tables have *columns* and *rows* not "fields".

Comment: The same as table 1 . So table 2 rows should go into table 1 columns. So sorry, yes, I have that wrong @Thom A

Comment: post a table with the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to pivot table2 and then insert.

Something like this... [FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/VYNSKS4d)

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (File_date, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3)  
  SELECT File_date
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 1 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_1
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 2 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_2
        , SUM(CASE WHEN cat_type = 3 THEN cat_count ELSE NULL END) AS cat_3
     FROM Table2
 GROUP BY File_date
  
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pivot to solve the problem

you can easy change List cat_? in pivot

```
insert into T1
(tdate,cat_1,cat_2,cat_3)

SELECT 
        tdate
       ,[1] as cat_1
       ,[2] as cat_2
       ,[3] as cat_3  
FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        tdate, 
        cat_type,
        cat_count
    FROM 
        T2
) t 
PIVOT(
    sum(cat_count) 
    FOR cat_type IN (
        [1], 
        [2], 
        [3] )
) AS pivot_table;
```

You can create insert base data  with the following statements:

```
drop table if exists  T1
CREATE TABLE T1 ( tdate DATE, cat_1 INT, cat_2 INT, cat_3 INT)
drop table if exists  T2
CREATE TABLE T2 (tdate DATE, cat_type INT, cat_count INT)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('2020-01-04',      2,        1)
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('2020-01-04',      3,        2);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('2020-01-05',      3,        2);
```